# How can I read a xml file and create blender properties depending on the xml data?

Tags: python

I have a xml file with a bunch of different data that I need parsed and created into properties to access. Here is a sample of the xml file

```
<ShaderPreSet name="default.sps" shader="default">
  <Bucket>0</Bucket>
  <SupportSkinning>True</SupportSkinning>
  <ShaderParameters>
    <Item name="DiffuseSampler" description="DiffuseTex" type="svt_sampler" registerIndex="0" isRequired="True">
      <Annotation key="UIName" type="string">Diffuse Texture</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="TCPTemplate" type="string">Diffuse</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="TextureType" type="string">Diffuse</Annotation>
    </Item>
    <Item name="matMaterialColorScale" description="MaterialColorScale" type="svt_float4" registerIndex="165" isRequired="False" value="1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000"/>
    <Item name="HardAlphaBlend" description="HardAlphaBlend" type="svt_float" registerIndex="164" isRequired="True" value="1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000">
      <Annotation key="UIName" type="string">Hard Alpha</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMin" type="float">0.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMax" type="float">1.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIStep" type="float">0.0100</Annotation>
    </Item>
    <Item name="UseTessellation" description="UseTessellation" type="svt_float" registerIndex="163" isRequired="True" value="0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000">
      <Annotation key="UIName" type="string">Use tessellation</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMin" type="float">0.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMax" type="float">1.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIStep" type="float">1.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="nostrip" type="int">1</Annotation>
    </Item>
    <Item name="WetnessMultiplier" description="WetnessMultiplier" type="svt_float" registerIndex="162" isRequired="False" value="1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000">
      <Annotation key="UIWidget" type="string">slider</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMin" type="float">0.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIMax" type="float">1.0000</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIStep" type="float">0.0050</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="UIName" type="string">Wetness multiplier</Annotation>
      <Annotation key="nostrip" type="int">1</Annotation>
    </Item>
    <Item name="GlobalAnimUV1" description="globalAnimUV1" type="svt_float3" registerIndex="161" isRequired="False" value="0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000"/>
    <Item name="GlobalAnimUV0" description="globalAnimUV0" type="svt_float3" registerIndex="160" isRequired="False" value="1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000"/>
  </ShaderParameters>
  <VertexDeclarations>
    <Name skinned="False">N209731BE</Name>
    <Name skinned="True">S1E9F420D</Name>
    <Name skinned="True">S032243A7</Name>
  </VertexDeclarations>
</ShaderPreSet>
```

Now for example I want to create a property that is for the  tag. I also want all the properties I create to be a property group and attached to the `bpy.types.Object` class. Anyone have a clue of how I could do this?

Comment: For the [xml part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/6879283).

Comment: Thanks but I understand basic python I just wanna know how to do this in the blender api, thanks though :)